# Centering bootstrap button group in an element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out the best way to center a Bootstrap button group (i.e., `btn-group`) within an element. So, for example, if you have this:

```
<div id='toolbar'>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How might I ensure that the `btn-group` is always centered within `toolbar` (assuming it can fit)? The way I came up with is as follows: I wrap a `div` around the `btn-group`, figure out the width of that `btn-group`, and then set that width on the wrapper along with `margin:0 auto`. However, there are two things I don't like about this approach:

(1) It requires trial and error to figure out exactly what the width of the `btn-group` is, through setting a border on the wrapper and continually reducing it until you find the right width.

(2) If the width of the content changes even by a pixel (e.g., button text changes, or it just looks different on a different machine because of their font settings, etc.) then it's no longer centered and the second button drops down a line. Of course, you could leave a few pixels of leeway here, but then the two buttons wouldn't actually be fully centered in the first place.

There must be a better way. Any ideas? Here's my approach ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmDL8/)):

**html**:

```
<div id='toolbar'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

#toolbar .wrapper {
    width: 197px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*border: 1px solid blue; used to test width*/
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use `.text-center` on the container since `.btn-group` is inline block: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmDL8/7/)

```
<div id='toolbar'>
    <div class='wrapper text-center'>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Command2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the more "Bootstrap-y" way. Of course, it's essentially the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since the button group uses `display: inline-block`, the correct way to center them would be

```
#toolbar .wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/USqQn/

(You can also apply the style to `#toolbar` and remove the `div.wrapper` entirely -- depending on whether you have anything else inside the toolbar. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/USqQn/1/)